# Twig Set Selected Value

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am new to Twig. Can someone please show me how to pass in the selected option value of a select box so that it is selected when the ajax form is loaded?

What am I doing wrong?

`warehouse_id = 32` in this example, and the `form_widget` automatically created my select list.

```
{{ form_widget(form.warehouse, {'selected': warehouse_id } ) }}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Normally you can have it auto rooted by passing the entity to the form.

Comment: Can we see how you build the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the easiest way that I found:

```
 {{ form_widget(form.field, {value: 1 } ) }}
```

Comment: I am using symfony 2.3, I observed id is required in double quotes.
I read from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270513/symfony2-twig-set-the-default-value-in-the-dropdownlist) and its working as well.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Look at the @GhanshyamKDobariya 's comment

Comment: If you're creating a form that's not attached to a doctrine entity, or you'd like to specify the selected value of a dropdown in twig, this is the correct answer. It's not clear in the symfony documents that setting value will select the choice specified, but it does do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do this. You can pass your entity (with data included) when form is created. Your dropdown will be with data selected.
See this code, for instance:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find($id);
if (!$entity) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find entity.');
}

$editForm = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $entity); 
//in entity goes with all data and your selectbox will be selected with correct data 
return $this->render('YourBundle:YourController:edit.html.twig', array(
    'entity'      => $entity,
    'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
));
```

or try to do this! Change 'selected' by 'value'

```
{{ form_widget(form.warehouse, {'value': warehouse_id } ) }}
```

Please, tell me about if you solved your doubt

Comment: For some reason that didn't work when I created the page via ajax. What I ended up doing was just passing the value into the ajax page and then doing this and it worked...

{{ form_widget(form.warehouse, {value: warehouse_id } ) }}