# Symfony2 - Twig : Set the default value in the dropdownlist

Tags: symfony, drop-down-menu, twig, default

I have a Form in my twig template. 
One of the form fields is a dropdownlist that is created from an Entity in my form builder.

I would like to set the default value in my dropdown list, to be the id 28 for example.

I don't know how to do this in twig.

I tryed this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.type, {value: 28 } ) }}
```

But nothing changed, I still have the firs value that is by default.

I know that I can set a default value in the FormType class where I am creating my form builder, but I am looking for a twig way, it seems to me more elegant than to create the object in the formType class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found my mistake, the code should be:

```
{{ form_widget(form.type, {value: "28" } ) }}
```

I forgot the quotes for the id. And also, there is a need to CTRL + F5 to refresh the page and see the difference.

Comment: Why -1, please argument.

Comment: Is this the right way of rendering control. {{ form_widget(form.skills,{'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass custom-select',value:"{{allocation.skills.skillsId }}", } }) }}
allocation.skills.skillsId is returning proper value.

Comment: You don't need the " in the value.

Comment: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" this error is thrown while writing  {{ form_widget(form.skills,{'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass custom-select', value : {{allocation.skills.skillsId }},} }) }}

Comment: for using a var, {{ form_widget(form.type, {value: your_twig_var ~ "" } ) }}

Answer (score 1):

```js
{{ form_widget(form.type, {value: twig_var ~ "" } ) }}
```

or

```js
{{ form_row(form.type, {value: twig_var ~ "" } ) }}
```

Comment: Why such information is missing in Twig docs? :(