# Set default value of select box in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270513/symfony2-twig-set-the-default-value-in-the-dropdownlist/18270625?noredirect=1#comment35313297_18270625) question

Code in twig is as below

```
{{ form_widget(form.skills,{ value : "{{allocation.skills.skillsId }}", 'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass', } }) }}
```

`form.skills` creates a select box, `{{allocation.skills.skillsId }}` always returns a valid value which exists in the select box.

But this code is not working while giving direct number constant works very fine.

```
{{ form_widget(form.skills,{ value : "5", 'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass', } }) }}
```

Can you say how to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you set the default value when you make the form ?
`$builder->add(...)`

Comment: Correct, actually this should be set automatically but there are some custom settings due to that at some place I am required to do such task manuallt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is incorrect, you should use this instead:

```
{{ form_widget(form.skills,{ value : allocation.skills.skillsId, 'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass', } }) }}
```

**NOTE**

value must be a string, so there are two ways you can achive this

- setting the default value in the form in your controller
- passing a string to the view
- "converting" the integer into a string in twig

**setting the default value in the form in your controller**

```
->add("skills", "choice", array("label" => "Skills", "choices" => $yourChoices, "attr" => array("class" => "right skillClass"), 'preferred_choices' => array(allocation.skills.skillsId)))
```

**passing a string to the view**

```
return $this->render("Bundle:view.html.twig", array("yourId" => (string)$yourId));
```

and the use `yourId` into the twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.skills,{ value : yourId, 'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass', } }) }}
```

**"converting" the integer into a string in twig** (very dirty)

```
{{ form_widget(form.skills,{ value : "" ~ allocation.skills.skillsId ~ "", 'attr': {'class': 'right skillClass', } }) }}
```

Comment: By fetching id from the object only.. value : "" ~ allocation.skills.skillsId ~ ""

Comment: I know this is not the right way, actually it should be set automatically, but I am working in maintenance of the proj, and some custom settings are there so this was required. but I am happy because I get to know new thing.